# Problems inserting elements into XML fragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

The basic problem is actually pretty simple:  I can't get a Nokogiri DocumentFragment to behave as expected.  It has two nodes instead of the one it would have if it were an actual document, and it doesn't recognize that node as an element, whereas the document does.

I need a fragment instead of a document, because I want to insert the resulting XML into another document (or fragment) as an element. It looks like I may have used the wrong fragment method.

I'm trying to build an XML representation for objects in our Ruby on Rails app, in a method called build_xml.  Since I have a hierarchy of nested objects, I'm making it a generic method that will be shared between classes, and use a class constant in each class to deal with class-specific info.  Each object creates a Nokogiri DocumentFragment instead of a full document, so that any returned XML string can be inserted into a containing object's XML as an element.

My problem is that I can't get the fragment to show me its elements.  So, I have:

```
xml_string = self.to_xml({skip_types:true, skip_instruct: true})  # Use default to_xml method to get started
xml_fragment = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml_string)  # Create Nokogiri doc fragment
```

And at this point, I want to loop over each nested object and add it as a sub-element of the fragment's only element.  However, the fragment's element_children() method returns an empty array, while it's children() method returns an array of two items, the first of which is the element I want, and the second of which is some text object, only containing a linefeed.

Example:

```
df = Datafile.first
xml_string = df.to_xml({skip_types:true, skip_instruct: true})
frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml_string)
frag.element_children  # => returns []
frag.children  # => returns array of two children, one of which is datafile element, the other of which is just a linefeed.
```

If I create an actual XML document instead of just a fragment, then the document has the element_children populated as expected, and furthermore, doc.children has only the one element, without the second, superfluous node.  I could try to do my work with a document, then just convert it to a fragment before returning it, but I don't know if resulting fragment will still have problems, and I'd prefer to understand what's going on, so I can just do it right, instead.

So...

1. Why doesn't the fragment recognize its only real node as an element?  Is there something I should do to force this?  The Nokogiri documentation doesn't describe much about element nodes, but it looks like they have no accessible properties to differentiate them from generic nodes.
2. Why does this second, empty node show up when I parse a fragment?
3. Do I just have to go through full documents?  Is there an easy way to cast a document to a fragment?
4. Should I be doing this some other way entirely?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really difficult to imagine what you're describing. Stack Overflow expects a minimal example of your input XML, along with code that demonstrates the problem, and an example of your desired output. See the "Help others reproduce the problem" section in "[ask]".

Comment: It isn't necessary to apologize for missing information, but we can't stress how important it is to give us the necessary information. Without that, we're guessing and shooting in the dark which only delays getting a working solution to you and frustrates us. Also, when adding additional information, please don't stick it at the start or end of the question and tag it with "Edit" or "Update". We can see edits/updates and the added information needs to be incorporated into the question where you would have added it originally, so it makes sense and reads correctly.

Comment: Also, remember, minimal examples of code and data are a LOT more useful than pages of explanation. The explanation helps define the intent, but the code shows us the path you're taking to get there. Like a picture, the examples are worth 1,000 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was just to update the version of Nokogiri.  Presumably, this was a bug that was fixed between versions 1.6.3.1 and 1.6.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in the whole XML string to `parse`, it just takes [the tags as an argument](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment#parse-class_method).

According to [their docs](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet#working-with-fragments), you should be doing something like this:

```
xml_fragment = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(xml_string)
```

Not sure if this is actually what's causing the problem, but it might be a place to start.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but I don't see a definition of `tags` on that page.  Is it an array of tag names, an XML string with the content of each tag empty, a specific type of Tags object, or something else?  I hope this doesn't sound demanding or belligerent, I'm just trying to fill in the gaps in the documentation (or my reading skills).

Comment: I tried `frag = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(xml_string)`, instead of the `DocumentFragment.parse` method, and it returns a fragment object, but that object still has two elements instead of one, and still doesn't recognize the meaningful node as an element (i.e. `frag.element_children` returns `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

While the question isn't clear, perhaps this little overview of inserting and removing nodes will help:

```
require 'nokogiri'

inserted_text = 'hello world!'
```

This parses the fragment:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')
doc.to_xml # => "<foo>\n  <bar/>\n</foo>"
```

Compare it to a full parse, which adds the XML declaration:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<foo>\n  <bar/>\n</foo>\n"
```

Find the `<bar>` node and add a child node:

```
bar = doc.at('bar')
bar.children = "<baz a='1'>#{ inserted_text }</baz>"

doc.to_xml # => "<foo>\n  <bar>\n    <baz a=\"1\">hello world!</baz>\n  </bar>\n</foo>"
```

I'm using the `at` method, which finds the first matching node. It's more specific than `search` which returns all matching nodes as a NodeSet, which is akin to an array of Nodes. Both methods take either CSS or XPath selectors; CSS is easier to read usually, but XPath has a lot more power so pick and choose between them based on ease of reading first, then the power. Nokogiri's perfectly happy to use both in the same script. There are CSS/XPath specific equivalents for `at` and `search`: `at_css`, `at_xpath` and `css` and `xpath` respectively. `at('some_selector')` is equivalent to `search('some_selector').first`.

Also, notice that Nokogiri is happy to take a string containing the XML or HTML you want to add. It will parse it into a fragment, allowing you to more easily define what you want to use.

This is how to easily remove a node:

```
baz = doc.at('baz').remove
```

To change an attribute of the node:

```
baz['a'] = 'hiya!'
```

And to move the node somewhere else:

```
doc.at('foo').add_child(baz)
```

This lets us see the node as XML:

```
doc.to_xml # => "<foo>\n  <bar/>\n  <baz a=\"hiya!\">hello world!</baz>\n</foo>"
```

This lets us see the XML as if we were looking at a file:

```
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <foo>
# >>   <bar/>
# >>   <baz a="hiya!">hello world!</baz>
# >> </foo>
```

Comment: So here's the crux of the issue.  In your example, once you create the **fragment** called doc, it has a foo element.  To verify this, you can execute `doc.children.first.element?`, and it returns `true`.  However, `doc.elements` returns `[]`.